# regex, substring of a url from start till the 3rd one of a certain character

Tags: regex, powershell, substring

Ok so I have a series of urls ranging from something like

```
http://www.test.com/sasa
http://www.test.com/sasdassasdssda
http://www.test.com/ewewewewsasa
http://www.test.com
```

What I want to do is just take a substring of each url which goes from the start to the third / and if there is no third / take the original string

basically I want to know how to get the position of the third /, as I assume if there is no third / then it will be -1 so I can just grab the position and if its not -1 do the substring bit.
Anyway enough of me rambling. How do I find the position of the third slash?

Comment: You can use `^([^/]*/){2}[^/]*` regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the URI without the path (the segment after the third `/`) and the trailing `/` itself.

The easiest way to do that, is simply to convert the string to an actual URI object and then use the `AbsoluteUri` and `PathAndQuery` properties to calculate where to make to incision:

```
function Get-UriSchemeAndAuthority
{
    param(
        [string]$InputString
    )

    $Uri = $InputString -as [uri]
    if($Uri){
        $FullUri = $Uri.AbsoluteUri
        $Path = $Uri.PathAndQuery

        $SlashIndex = $FullUri.Length - $Path.Length

        return $FullUri.Substring(0,$SlashIndex)
    } else {
        throw "Malformed URI"
    }
}
```

Works with all of your test cases:

```
PS C:\> Get-UriSchemeAndAuthority http://www.test.com/sasa
http://www.test.com
PS C:\> Get-UriSchemeAndAuthority http://www.test.com/sasdassasdssda
http://www.test.com
PS C:\> Get-UriSchemeAndAuthority http://www.test.com/ewewewewsasa
http://www.test.com
PS C:\> Get-UriSchemeAndAuthority http://www.test.com
http://www.test.com
```

---

Alternatively, take the `Scheme` and `Authority` properties and create a new string from those (makes it much more concise) :

```
function Get-UriSchemeAndAuthority
{
    param(
        [string]$InputString
    )

    $Uri = $InputString -as [uri]
    if($Uri){
        return $("{0}://{1}" -f $Uri.Scheme,$Uri.Authority)
    } else {
        throw "Malformed URI"
    }
}
```